# MarkLogic: cts:highlight with specific element

Tags: xml, search, marklogic, highlight

We have xml like this

```
<paper>
   <title>blue</title>
   <description>red and blue</description>
   <headline>red color pen</headline>
   <elm1>
      <term>abc</term>
   </elm1>
   <elm2>
      <term>abc</term>
   <elm2>
</paper>
```

We want to run Marklogic query with full document where we want to highlight word "red"

used search:search to get data, then we are calling cts:highlight to highlight word "red" in xml

it works fine

Now i want to search only in specific element i.e. description, it should highlight "red" only in description element, how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either wrap your current query in `cts:element-query`:

```
cts:element-query(xs:QName('description'), cts:word-query('red'))
```

or use `cts:element-word-query`:

```
cts:element-word-query(xs:QName('description'),'red')
```

Comment: Thanks wst for quick reply
Ok, will check with this

what if i need to do that for 2/3 elements in same result ?

Comment: Both queries accept a sequence as first argument. If you need nesting, just nest in more element-queries.

Comment: We have 2 more scenarios now. 1. user search for "physics and Chemistry", so whatever results comes, full phrase should be highlighted, how to ? we can't split and highlight. 2. now if i search "abc" only in /elm1/term element, its working, now while implementing highlight word using element query, "abc" in both xml nodes are highlighted as both have same element name, how to implement highlight here?